# CORS error on requesting OWIN token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, cors

I need to implement OWIN authorization from web api server. Below is my startup class.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SpaServerSide.MyStartUp))]

namespace SpaServerSide
{
    public class MyStartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {            
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfig = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration { };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfig);
            });


            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/#")
            });


            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                Provider = new SpaServerSide.Shared.OAuthTokenServer()               
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }
    }
}
```

Then, I implement the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider as the following :

```
public class OAuthTokenServer : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public ASPIdentityUserManager cusUserManager;       

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
            var user = await cusUserManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Username and password do not match.");
                return;
            }
            var identity = await cusUserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            context.Validated(identity);
        }

    }
```

After that, I have hosted the web server on http://localhost:5587 and client web site on http://localhost. When I tried to request the token using Angular JS, the browser threw me an CORS error. The message is as follows :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:5587/Token. (Reason: CORS
>   header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Please suggest me anything I would have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line:
    `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

at the beginning of your `Configuration()` method.

You have to configure CORS middleware before oauth middleware. And before signalr middleware if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Enable browser setting for allowing cross origin access

IE: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Firefox: [How to enable CORS on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504851/how-to-enable-cors-on-firefox)

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: A quote from one of the link  
>Do nothing to the browser. CORS is supported by default on all  modern browsers (and since Firefox 3.5).



The server being accessed by JavaScript has to give the site hosting the HTML document in which the JS is running permission via CORS HTTP response headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need enable CORS in your server side. U can refer to this http://enable-cors.org/server.html . Click link based on your server.

Hope that help u. :)

Comment: Tried that `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` on the StartUp class and `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });` on the provider class.